# How to get the current collection of mediaitems in ipod player?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have an application with [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].

When the app is open, I want to get the current collection of mediaitems that is playing now.

How can I do that ?
Somthing like :  [MPMediaQuery currentQuery];

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want the contents of the user's iPod library? Or do you want to know which specific asset (music, video, whatever) is playing right now?

Comment: I want to know what collection of songs is playing right now. for example, the user select "all albums of x artist" in the ipod player application(not im my application).

I want to check the current collection when my app is starting, to show the correct info.

Comment: UPDATE:on other site, I read the iphone sdk not allow to get the current playback queue in anyway. The only way to get it, is to create it and save in property. So probably you can not get the queue that is currently played in the built-in ipod application.

This also means you can not get the playback queue and display the songs list on shuffle mode. only create the shuffle by yourself.